# How Widespread Is the Application of MDPs in Medical Decision Making?

Tags: reference-request, markov-decision-process, implementation, practical-or, medical-application

I'm curious about the current prevalence of Markov Decision Processes (MDPs) in medical decision-making. I've seen several research papers on this topic but was unable to find evidence of real-world implementations. Could you share examples of the widespread use of MDPs in the medical field (preferably with references)?